# LSTM giving almost constant output

Tags: time-series, lstm, prediction

I have used an LSTM with 4 layers deep each layer having 10 LSTM units to predict the AAPL stock 500 steps away by looking 50 steps back and it was predicting well (only a lag was there).

However when I try to predict the difference (future stock value- current stock value), I am getting an almost flat curve.

[image]

In this plot, the two (full) verticle lines are the validation split and train-test splits. The blue curve is the true value and orange curve is the predicted value.
Now, as you can see, the prediction in the validation and test is always constant.

Then I thought may be this is because the model is not having enough flexibility and increased number of LSTMs in each layer, but that did not help.

Further I tried to map the differences to bins and the results was the same (see the image below)
[image]

However in the otherhand, an MLP with few financial features (4 layers deep with each layer having 10 neurons) was doing a better job.

In here I have used 1 minute data and there was around 3.5million datapoints in the full time-series.

Any idea why is this happening?